# M2MQTT client disconnecting without an exception or error message

Tags: c#, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to create an API that consumes various topics.
For this, I'm trying to multi-thread things, so that the whole thing can be scalable into multiple APIs, later on, but that's very besides the point.

I'm using ASP.net Core 4.0, if that's got anything to do with it. Entity Framework as well.

My problem is based on my connection to my Mosquitto server being broken without throwing an exception or anything of the like, after a minute or so. It doesn't matter how big the messages are, or how many are exchanged. I have no idea of how I can create a callback or anything of the kind to know what's going on with my connection. Can anyone help?

I'll link the code I use to establish a connection and subscribe to a connection below. Using the Subscribe method or doing it manually also changes nothing. I'm at a loss, here.

Thanks in advance!

Main.cs:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DataflowController.ResumeQueuesAsync());
BuildWebHost(args).Run();
```

DataflowController.cs:

```
public static Boolean Subscribe(String topic)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Hello from " + topic);

        MqttClient mqttClient = new MqttClient(brokerAddress);
        byte code = mqttClient.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        // Register to message received
        mqttClient.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_recievedMessageAsync;

        string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        mqttClient.Connect(clientId);

        // Subscribe to topic
        mqttClient.Subscribe(new String[] { topic }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
        System.Console.ReadLine();

        return true;
    }

    public static async Task ResumeQueuesAsync()
    {
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase(databaseName);

        var topics = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(topicCollection);
        var filter = new BsonDocument();
        List<BsonDocument> result = topics.Find(filter).ToList();
        var resultSize = result.Count;
        Task[] subscriptions = new Task[resultSize];

        MqttClient mqttClient = new MqttClient(brokerAddress);
        byte code = mqttClient.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        // Register to message received
        mqttClient.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_recievedMessageAsync;

        string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        mqttClient.Connect(clientId);


        int counter = 0;
        foreach(var doc in result)
        {

            subscriptions[counter] = new Task(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello from " + doc["topic"].ToString());
                // Subscribe to topic
                mqttClient.Subscribe(new String[] { doc["topic"].ToString() }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
                System.Console.ReadLine();
            });
            counter++;
        }

        foreach(Task task in subscriptions)
        {
            task.Start();
        }
    }

    static async void client_recievedMessageAsync(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle message received
        var message = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Message);
        var topic = e.Topic;

        var id = topic.Split("/")[2];

        BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument {
            {"Plug ID", id },
            {"Consumption", message }
        };

        await Save(doc, "smartPDM_consumption");

        System.Console.WriteLine("Message received from " + topic + " : " + message);
    }
```

Comment: Does the broker log give any indication as to why the client disconnected?

Comment: The broker doesn't even notice the client disconnecting. However, I have fixed the issue. This line was the issue:

`byte code = mqttClient.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());`

Comment: If you have a solution please add it as a proper answer (with a more detailed description of what you did to fix it) so other might benefit. You should also mark it as accepted, you'll get more points and a medal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was the issue:

```
byte code = mqttClient.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Deleted it, and it just worked.